# How to make a wxPython MessageDialog that allows the user to copy/paste the text in it?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

The MessageDialog that I created in wxPython is not interactive and does not allow the user to select and copy the text in it. Is there another similar wxPython widget I could use, or something I could do to my existing MessageDialog? The following is the code I have thus far:

`box = wx.MessageDialog(parent, "This is my text", "This is my title", style=wx.ICON_ERROR|wx.OK)`

Thank you! I appreciate your help.

Comment: So if I select the text control inside this dialog and press `Ctrl + V` or press right mouse button, what happened? Also, what OS do you try it on, what python version and is wxPython version? Do you use classic or Phoenix? Also, what do you mean by saying `it is not interactive`?

Comment: Under MSW the standard dialog does support `Ctrl+C` for copying its text. Somehow almost nobody seems to know about this feature even though it dates back to Windows 3.11 AFAIR (and possibly earlier).

Comment: You could use the `ScrolledMessageDialog` I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

A [TextCtrl](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.TextCtrl.html) allows the user to type text, and copy & paste as well.

Many samples [here](https://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial)

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you cannot grab the entire MessageDialog, you certainly can capture the message text. You need to click on the text to select it with your mouse or right click and choose `select all`. With the text selected, right click gives you the option to `copy`, as seen in this screen shot.
Caveats: On linux and using wxpython 3.0 classic

[image]

If you wish to copy and paste then perhaps you need a `TextEntryDialog`

```
import wx
app = wx.App()
dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(None,"Copy and Paste below","heading","This is my text")
dlg.SetSize((600,180))
if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
    text = dlg.GetValue()
    print text
dlg.Destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the wx.TE_READONLY on TextCtrl creates a box where text can not be edited but can be copy-pasted

Example:

```
wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, outStr , style=wx.TE_BESTWRAP|wx.TE_READONLY)
```